# flash navigation bar in html/css/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, navigation

I am hoping to build my navigation bar into something like:

http://www.taylorhowes.com/#/portfolio/knightsbridge?imageid=1

where the navigation links appear and disappear on mouseover from a specified area of the page. Is this possible without using Flash (I have CS5 but have never used Flash before and find it all slightly daunting!!).

If this is possible in css and javascript, does anyone know of anywhere online where I could find a tutorial or a script to manipulate to implement on my site?

Thanks!

JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve similar effects using JavaScript and CSS.

There are some javascript navigations that you can copy & paste to your site, for example: http://www.menubasic.com/Menu/Menus.aspx?p=1

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely possible to do without Flash.  Look into [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  Specifically:  http://api.jquery.com/animate/

There are so many things here, it is hard to point you in a specific direction, but that should get you started with what you want to do.